# How can I calculate dyadics in matlab without using for loops?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I was wondering if someone could help me with my problem.

Let say that I have the coordinates of MxN vectors in a tensor r of dimensions [M,N,3]. I would like to save in a 3M-by-3N block matrix all dyadic products r_0'*r_0, where r_0 is the vector r_0 = r(m,n,:) for some m and n, and I would like to do this without using for loops.

If haven't explain myself correctly, here is an example code that shows what I would like to obtain (but using for loops, of course):

```
N=10;
M=5;
r=rand(M,N,3);
Dyadic=zeros(3*M,3*N);
for m=1:M
    a1=3*m-2;
    a2=3*m;
    for n=1:N
        b1=3*n-2;
        b2=3*n;
        aux(3)=r(m,n,3);
        aux(2)=r(m,n,2);
        aux(1)=r(m,n,1);
        Dyadic(a1:a2,b1:b2)=transpose(aux)*aux
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the posted solution worked for you, consider accepting it by clicking on the hollow checkmark next to the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `bsxfun(@times` and then re-arrange elements to have the desired output -

```
%// Get the multipliication result
mat_mult = bsxfun(@times,permute(r,[1 2 4 3]),r);
 %// OR if you would like to keep mat_mult as 3D that could be potentially faster -
 %//     mat_mult = bsxfun(@times,reshape(r,[],3),permute(reshape(r,[],3),[1 3 2]));

%// Re-arrange elements to have them the way you are indexing in nested loops
Dyadic = reshape(permute(reshape(mat_mult,M,N,3,[]),[3 1 4 2]),M*3,N*3);
```

The major play about this solution is really the re-arrangement of elements after we have the multiplication result.

**Quick runtime tests** with the input `r` as `1000 x 1000 x 3` sized array, show that this `bsxfun` based approach gives over **`20x`** speedup over the nested loop code listed in the question!

Comment: @LuisMendo haha yeahh worked out this time in favor of `bsxfun(@times`..for a change !!